# Exporting a React Application as static HTML

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I've created a new React application.  As it stands, it just the template from Visual Studio; New Project -> Asp.Net Core -> React.

When the application runs, there is an element of dynamic content displayed on the screen.  What I want to be able to do is to get some kind of HTML dump of this page, such that I could paste it into a static web application and have the same screen rendered.

I've had a look around, and have found a few tools, such as [react-snapshot](https://github.com/geelen/react-snapshot) which appear to do what I want; however, it seems to be that you're in or out; that is, you either have it dynamically rendered or statically rendered.  I just want a static dump of the HTML, and would like to leave the rendering as is.

For example, inside my Javascript, I have the following code:

```
const htmlSection = document.getElementById("MyHtml");
// Export Html Here
```

Is this kind of thing possible and, if so, how can it be achieved in code?

Comment: The browsers should be able to provide you source of the current state of the page.  Have you tried to save the page as HTML or copy/paste the code from the developer tools?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase my question right - I've updated it now.  Yes: save page source works fine and creates the HTML page.  I want to be able to do this from within the React application itself

Comment: Print functionality is browser dependent.  You will most likely need to create a new document using the source of the current document (I.e. `document.querySelector('html').innerHTML`) and automatically calling `window.print()` when creating that page

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
    const handleExport = () => {

        const link = document.createElement("a");

        // Create a blog object with the file content which you want to add to the file
        const file = new Blob([document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML], { type: 'text/plain' });

        // Add file content in the object URL
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        // Add file name
        link.download = "sample.html";

        // Add click event to <a> tag to save file.
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
    }
```

The HTML and module style can be exported, but the problem is that is javascript event can not be remained anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `fs` module to read your index file something like this:
`fs.readFileSync(path[, options])`