# React how to export html and javascript as a file after React finish rendering on client

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Background**

I have a React client application.

**Demand**

I have a demand that I need to export the static HTML file after clicking a button.
Similar question  is here

[Exporting a React Application as static HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188307/exporting-a-react-application-as-static-html/74759948#74759948)

Two conditions must be satisfied.

1. The static HTML must include the data state at the time when I click the export button.
2. The static HTML must include the javascript event. For example, the submit button should also works at static HTML file.

**Current Develop Status**

I tried to do this with the following React code.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ListComponent from './List'

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [names, setNames] = useState([])

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        setNames(n => ([...n, name]))
        setName('')
    }

    console.log(names)

    const handleExport = () => {

        const link = document.createElement("a");

        // Create a blog object with the file content which you want to add to the file
        const file = new Blob([document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML], { type: 'text/plain' });

        // Add file content in the object URL
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        // Add file name
        link.download = "sample.html";

        // Add click event to <a> tag to save file.
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
    }

    return (<div>
        <div>App</div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleExport}>export</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name='name' value={name} onChange={e=>setName(e.target.value)}></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>submit</button>
        </div>
        <ListComponent names={names}/>
    </div>)
};

export default App
```

List.jsx

```
import styles from './List.module.css'

const ListComponent = (props) => {
    const { names } = props
    return <div>
        
        {names.map(n => {
            return <div className={styles.list}>
                <p className={styles.name}>name:</p>
                <p className={styles.value}>{n}</p>
            </div>
        })}

    </div>
}

export default ListComponent
```

List.module.css

```
.list {
    display: flex;
}
  
.name {
color: blue;
}

.value {
color: yellow;
}
```

The implementation above can satisfy the first condition, but I don't know how to satisfy the second condition.

**Exported static HTML opened by browser**

[image: This is exported static HTML opened by browser]

**The exported static HTML file's source code**

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=SH0n3G5o7aoVFLdOGJoBAKQJTHqbJEXTc4T368hGQh5joL1rf2F9cXiJO9goBfwn" charset="UTF-8"></script><script defer="" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><style>body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,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 */</style><style>.List_list__EzJ7j {
    display: flex;
}
  
.List_name__toj2i {
color: blue;
}

.List_value__gvADR {
color: yellow;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIndlYnBhY2s6Ly8uL3NyYy9MaXN0Lm1vZHVsZS5jc3MiXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IkFBQUE7SUFDSSxhQUFhO0FBQ2pCOztBQUVBO0FBQ0EsV0FBVztBQUNYOztBQUVBO0FBQ0EsYUFBYTtBQUNiIiwic291cmNlc0NvbnRlbnQiOlsiLmxpc3Qge1xyXG4gICAgZGlzcGxheTogZmxleDtcclxufVxyXG4gIFxyXG4ubmFtZSB7XHJcbmNvbG9yOiBibHVlO1xyXG59XHJcblxyXG4udmFsdWUge1xyXG5jb2xvcjogeWVsbG93O1xyXG59Il0sInNvdXJjZVJvb3QiOiIifQ== */</style></head>
  <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1088.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"><div><div>App</div><div><button>export</button></div><div><input name="name" value=""></div><div><button>submit</button></div><div><div class="List_list__EzJ7j"><p class="List_name__toj2i">name:</p><p class="List_value__gvADR">asdas</p></div><div class="List_list__EzJ7j"><p class="List_name__toj2i">name:</p><p class="List_value__gvADR">asd</p></div><div class="List_list__EzJ7j"><p class="List_name__toj2i">name:</p><p class="List_value__gvADR">asd</p></div><div class="List_list__EzJ7j"><p class="List_name__toj2i">name:</p><p class="List_value__gvADR">asd</p></div></div></div></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  

</body><grammarly-desktop-integration data-grammarly-shadow-root="true"></grammarly-desktop-integration>
```

**The Problem**

The name list is remained as what I expected but the submit button could not be clicked anymore.
That is because the javascript code controlling event logic is not exported during HTML export.

When I import the bundle.js which is generated during npm run start. The submit button can be clicked but the name list is lost. That is because bundle.js contains React code which will force rendering page from mount stage.

**Submit button can be clicked but page is rendering again**

[image: submit button can be clicked but page is rendering again]

**My Question**

Is there a way to export a static HTML including both dom and styles and javascript event?

Comment: One option is to inline all of your JavaScript, including React. The resulting HTML page will be big, but...

Comment: All that the submit button in the question does is clear the names. It doesn't actually submit anything anywhere. Is that really what the button is supposed to do?

Comment: It do setNames
I use submit button to update names